How to "require" a LUA script within a Spoon-package?
We have base LUA file ~/.hammerspoon/init.lua which can load a spoon package:
hs.loadSpoon("Foo")

Now we have our package file init.lua by path:
~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/init.lua
It works fine.
I create a file my/bar.lua inside this package. Full path:
`~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/my/bar.lua`

with code:
return {}

and it should be included in ~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/init.lua:
local bar = require("Foo.Spoon.my.bar")

We will see similar error:
Error loading Foo:..poon.app/Contents/Resources/extensions/hs/_coresetup.lua:662: module 'Foo.Spoon/my/bar' not found:
no field package.preload['Foo.Spoon/my/bar']
no file '/Users/me/.hammerspoon/Foo/Spoon/my/bar.lua' no file '/Users/me/.hammerspoon/Foo/Spoon/my/bar/init.lua'
no file /Users/me/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo/Spoon/my/bar.spoon/init.luat26:
no file opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/Foo/Spoon/my/bar.lua'
...

I played with various options like

require("my.bar")
require("Foo.my.bar")

all of them fail.
Problem
In case of using require("Foo.Spoon.my.bar"), it looks like the loader the loader always replaces "." with "/" which breaks options to mention the package folder Foo.Spoon.
But it suppose to keep "Foo.Spoon" instead of "Foo/Spoon". And it does not:
no file '/Users/me/.hammerspoon/Foo/Spoon/my/bar.lua' no file 

According to logs it obviously walks around, but does not look at the Foo.Spoon directory (tried .spoon it in lowercase too), which is strange.
Any advice/workaround (but without changing "require" function, or using absolute paths)?..
P.S. I took a look at related other posts.

Since the init script works fine, you can append the directory of the init script to package.searchpath, so that lua is able to find the module from this directory.
-- modulePath will be resolved as '~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/init.lua'
local modulePath = package.searchpath('Foo', package.path)

-- Remove 'init.lua'
modulePath = modulePath:match('(.*/)')

-- Append ';~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/?.lua' to package.path
package.path = package.path .. ';' .. modulePath .. '?.lua'

-- Now the following code will resolve the module path as 
-- '~/.hammerspoon/Spoons/Foo.Spoon/my/bar.lua'
local bar = require("my.bar")


According to the Hammerspoon docs on spoon development you can not use require and should instead use the following:
dofile(hs.spoons.resourcePath("someCode.lua"))

